# Can a subdomain have different CNAME records or must the entire domain have the same CNAME?

Tags: cname

Like my question asks - should the entire DNS/CNAME be the same for the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You should delete this and ask, instead, on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Any domain can have its own CNAME record. In most practical situations, the 'main' / apex domain (For example `foo.com`) can usually not get a CNAME record. But otherwise every CNAME record is for a specific (sub-)domain, and every CNAME record can point to something else.